# Returning unique values in a MS Access query based upon a set a rules

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query that returns a dataset with UserID, CourseID, Course Completion date, Course Registration Date and Status (successful, not attempted, not finished).

However people are allowed to do a course multiple times.

For 1 report I need to get a unique recordset (*based upon the Combination UserID and CourseID*) back according to the following rules:

1. If a course is completed successfully by a learner take only that value
2. If a course is completed successfully by a learner multiple times, take the first completion date.
3. if a course not completed successfully by a learner take the last registration date.

I know how to create a query that only returns unique (Distinct) values, but not how to do it with a set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is a bit older. I don't know if this directly answers your question because I couldn't think of a way to write a single query to do this. I did however come up with a solution that I tested myself.

Using 3 tables and 4 queries, I think that I have produced the results you're looking for.

The first query I wrote was to get the "First Completed" dates. Since if a person only completes a course once, that is their first completion, this actually means your criteria 1 and 2 are identical.

I did this by grouping on the UserID and the CourseID and then taking the aggregate MIN of the CourseCompleteionDate where the Status is equal to 1.

```
SELECT tblRegistrations.UserID, tblRegistrations.CourseID, Min(tblRegistrations.CourseCompletionDate) AS FirstCompleted
FROM tblRegistrations
WHERE ((tblRegistrations.StatusID)=1)
GROUP BY tblRegistrations.UserID, tblRegistrations.CourseID;
```

The second query I wrote was to get the "Last Not Completed" registration dates. Again I grouped on the UserID and the CourseID, but this time I took the aggregate MAX of the CourseRegistrationDate to get the last time this course was attempted and not completed (with a status equal to 3)

```
SELECT tblRegistrations.UserID, tblRegistrations.CourseID, Max(tblRegistrations.CourseRegistrationDate) AS LastAttempt
FROM tblRegistrations
WHERE (((tblRegistrations.StatusID)=3))
GROUP BY tblRegistrations.UserID, tblRegistrations.CourseID;
```

The third query I wrote was to get the unique UserID/CourseID relationships, and that simply grouped them.

```
SELECT tblRegistrations.CourseID, tblRegistrations.UserID
FROM tblRegistrations
GROUP BY tblRegistrations.CourseID, tblRegistrations.UserID;
```

Finally, I wrote my result query which makes sure to pull every UserID/CourseID combination, and then show whether it was completed or not, and the requested date.

```
SELECT qryUserCourses.UserID, qryUserCourses.CourseID, Nz([FirstCompleted],[LastAttempt]) AS ResultDate, IIf([FirstCompleted],"Completed","Not Completed") AS Result
FROM (qryUserCourses 
LEFT JOIN qryFirstCompleted ON (qryUserCourses.CourseID = qryFirstCompleted.CourseID) AND (qryUserCourses.UserID = qryFirstCompleted.UserID)) 
LEFT JOIN qryLastNotCompleted ON (qryUserCourses.CourseID = qryLastNotCompleted.CourseID) AND (qryUserCourses.UserID = qryLastNotCompleted.UserID);
```

This produced, for me, a list of UserIDs, CourseIDs, a date, and completion status.